# Let $f:A\to B$. For each $B\subset T$, we have $f[f^{-1}[B]]=B$ iff $B\subset range(f)$

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $f:S\to T$. For each $B\subset T$, we have $f[f^{-1}[B]]=B$ iff $B\subset range(f)$

I have the following to prove the $\to$ of the iff:

Let $B\subset T$. Suppose $f[f^{-1}[B]]=B$. *Then, $f^{-1}[B]\cap f^{-1}[B\setminus T] = \emptyset$. **Thus, for each $x\in A$, there is some $y\in B$ such that $f(x)=y$. Thus, $y\in range(y)$. So, $B\subset range(f)$.

I think this follows, but I am unsure about the jump from * to **. Is this logic correct? I am still new to working with images and pre images.

Thanks!

Comment: What    is    $T$?    .     .

Comment: Sorry. $f:S\to T$, not $f:A\to B$

Answer (score 0):

Just put one foot in front of the other.

Let $B\subseteq T$.

Suppose * $f[f^{-1}[B]]=B$. We need to show $B\subseteq \text{ran}(f)$. Well, let $b\in B$. By *, there exists $x\in f^{-1}[B]$ such that $f(x)=b$. Thus $b\in\text{ran}(f)$.

Now try the other direction. Hint: To show two sets are equal, show each is a subset of the other.

Comment: Why do we need * to show that there is some $x\in f^{-1}[B]$ such that $f(x)=b$? Isn't that true without *?

Edit: I think I understand now

Comment: How would you go about doing the other way. I have: 

Suppose $y\subset range(f)$. Then, for some $y\in B$, we have $y\in range(f)$. Thus, there is some $x\in A$ such that $f(x)=y$. 

But how do I show that then $y\in f[f^{-1}[B]]$?